# Can I massage the data bound to my struct using Gin-gonic?

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm using `c.Bind` like so:

```
// Customer represents a patient row.
type Customer struct {
    CustomerID     uuid.UUID `form:"customer_id"`
    FirstName      string    `form:"first_name"`
    MiddleName     string    `form:"middle_name"`
    LastName       string    `form:"last_name"`
    Email          string    `form:"email"`
    Address        string    `form:"address"`
    Address2       string    `form:"address2"`
    City           string    `form:"city"`
    Province       string    `form:"province"`
    PostalCode     string    `form:"postal_code"`
    PrimaryPhone   string    `form:"primary_phone"`
    SecondaryPhone string    `form:"secondary_phone"`
    Gender         string    `form:"gender"`
    DateOfBirth    time.Time `form:"date_of_birth" time_format:"01/02/2006" time_utc:"1"`
}


type customerFormData struct {
    C      Customer
    ErrStr string
}

// Create creates a new customer object, validates it, and inserts it into the database, rendering the new customer
// form on error.
func Create(c *gin.Context) {
    var f customerFormData
    c.Bind(&f)

    // do stuff with f
}
```

Is it possible to insert a data-massaging step into the bind, to e.g. remove dashes from phone number fields?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you should do that, because that would mean every single request will try to perform this data manipulation, even where it is not needed. Another way to get around this would be to write a method on your `customerData` struct called `dataMassaging` and call that function when needed. That way, you can choose at the handler level whether or not to call it and test it seperately. An example of doing that would be

```
func (c *customerData)  DataMassaging(){
    /*your code goes here*/
   }
```